# Even symmetric group, every element a product of cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is a question on different ways to establish a property of the symmetric group.

Suppose $j$ less than equal to $k$ is an even number.

I am wondering, what are some of the different ways it can be seen that every element in $S_k$ can be represented as a product of $j$-cycles?

Comment: You should add after "$j$-cycles" : with **disjoint support**. Otherwise, as any permutation is the product of a certain number of transpositions, the result would be general... Besides, what do you mean when saying "$j$ less than equal $k$" ?

Comment: @Jean Marie: he means all the cycles should have the same length $j$. This is not about the decomposition into disjoint cycles, more like " any permutation is a product of $2$ cycles"  ( $j=2$)

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks. I should have read more attentively....

Answer (score 0):

More of a hint.

Fix a $j$. The subgroup generated by cycles of length $j$ is normal, since every conjugate of a cycle of length $j$ is again such a cycle. Now, for $n\ge 5$ there are only $3$ normal subgroups of $S_n$: $1$, $A_n$ and $S_n$. If $j$ is ever, every $j$ cycle is odd. Therefore, the subgroup must be $S_n$.

A direct way would be to show that if $j$ is every, every $2$ cycle is a product of $j$ cycles.